# Is there an online random setting generator?

Tags: system-agnostic, tools

Ages ago, when I was still pretty new to the whole role-playing thing, I came across an online app for generating random settings for RPGs (or novels, comics, whatever). I've searched for it several times but I've been unable to find it or anything like it again.

The way it worked was by having several different categories, such as: Tech level, Magic level, how gods worked, what societies were present, etc. When you generated a setting each of those categories got shuffled, and the combinations were where the magic came from.

The best feature though, was the locking option. By locking which categories you liked you could re-roll everything else to get a different flavor. By repeating this a few times, locking your preferred categories as they came up, it was a sure-fire way to come up with an engaging setting.

The first time I used it as a lark to try out a new game system I picked up, and we ended up playing that setting for years!

**Does anyone remember this app and where it can be found? Or does anyone know of other tools that work in the same way?**

Answer (score 12):

This sounds like the Chaotic Shiny [Civilization Generator](http://chaoticshiny.com/civgen.php). The customisation of the generator used to be finer-grained and appears to have been reduced since I last used it, but it still generates all the categories you mention.

Comment: I love Chaotic Shiny! I haven't seen this one before, but while this is a good generator, it lacks the necessary locking mechanism for categories. Can you elaborate on what's been reduced?